# How to subtract all the date columns from each other (in permutation) and store them in a new pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, subtraction

I was working on Jupyter and arrived at a situation where I had to take differences of each column from every other column taken in permutation and then store them in a separate DataFrame. I tried using nested loops but got stuck while assigning the values to the DataFrame.

```
n=0
for i in range(len(list(df.columns))-1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(list(df.columns))-1):
    df1[n] = pd.DataFrame(abs((df.iloc[:,i] - df.iloc[:,j]).dt.days))
    n=n+1
df1
```

Also, I would like to have column headers in this format: D1-D2, D1-D3, etc. The difference in dates has to be a positive integer. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this code. Thanks!

[A snippet of the DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnNJh.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"co1":[1,2,3,4], "co22":[4,3,2,1], "co3":[2,3,2,4]})

# iterate over all permutations of size 2 and write to dictionary
newcols = {}
for col1, col2 in itertools.permutations(df.columns, 2):
    newcols["-".join([col1, col2])] = df[col1]-df[col2]

# create dataframe from dict
newdf = pd.DataFrame(newcols)
```

Comment: Hey, @tomanizer, Thanks a lot. The code works, however, I wish there was a way to only take unique permutations. For example, the code gives both, col1 - col2 and col2 - col1. However, I just need one of them.

Comment: which one do you want to pick? col1-col2 or col2-col1?

Comment: if you could accommodate the absolute function, then any one of the pairs would do. Preferably, a consistent dataframe having abs(col1 - col2) values

Comment: Hey @tomanizer, itertools.combination did the job for me. Is there a way I can keep all my final values numeric? The presence of NaN values in my dataset changes everything to a float.

Comment: to drop NAs, use dropna() on your dataframe. to cast a column use as_type() on the column you cant to cast. float in pandas is a numeric value. did you mean integer?